# strict doctype causeing css jquery problems in ie

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I use this code: http://blogswizards.com/plugin-development/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery

On a simple gallery site I am building. Specifically I use the last effect:

//Caption Sliding (Partially Hidden to Visible)

```
$('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
  $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'185px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
}, function() {
  // ending position of the caption... measured from top.
  $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'228px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
});
```

I am now trying to integrate Shadow box for the full view of each image: http://www.shadowbox-js.com

My problem is that when I incorporate the doc type into my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

The sliding captions behave incorrectly in IE. That is they slide appear at the top of the caption box and then when the mouse goes over them then move to their correct mouse over position and then back to a correct stating position. But their initial start position:

```css
.caption .boxcaption {
   /* starting position of caption box. measured from top of image box*/
    top: 228;
    left: 0;
 }
```

Does not work. If I remove the doc type the sliding captions function correctly but shadowbox (and other lightbox type popups) do not because they require the doc type to be set to work correctly...

And this is all just in IE. Works fine in FF and Chrome regardless.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> top: 228;
> ```

top: 228px;

The [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) can be useful to catch simple typos like this.